# Database is locked crash in sqlite3 database in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

In my current app I have nearly 10 scenarios of **inserting, updating , deleting and selecting** the data into and from the **sqlite3** database. Now for every query Iam opening the database and closing the database this makes my app very slow.
    I have tried other way like  opened  the database at the launch of app `(applicationDidBecomeActive:)`and closed the database when app terminates`(applicationWillResignActive/ applicationWillTerminate:)` only once.
This is working only when we install the app first time.Once i deleted the current build and relaunching the app is not working. The error is Database is locked. Please help me. which way is the better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of opening your database every time

What you can do

1) Initialize an instance of NSMutableArray in your AppDelegate Class and set its property strong and nonatomic.

```
for example @property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *temp;
```

2) Take a backup of your database in temp i.e NSMutableArray object

3) Perform an operation inserting, updating , deleting and selecting the data into temp i.e. NSMutableArray object

4) In background, perform same operation in your database. So, this will block your UI section.

Through this process, you are performing all your operation in an array not directly to your database. This will help not to open your database every time and will make your application little bit faster.

Comment: Iam writing 2000 contacts into the database, taking time.I have run this process in background.When I tap on a button it should display all the contacts from the database.this causing crash database is locked and Sqlite3_statement is null.

Comment: @SudhakarTharigoppula What i am saying that instead of opening a database every time, what you can do have a backup of your database in an array object. This will simplifies your burden.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your database was closed correctly ?

If it was not closed correctly, your database can become corrupted.
The file should not be locked by the OS anymore past the end of the application (if this application is not configured to run in background of course).

When you close your database, are you sure that all statements are finished and finalized ?

Answer (score -1):

try opening your database in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

this methods everytime your application is launched

Comment: is this right process of doing opening and closing database or is there any better way to do.And How can I check whether database is closed or not.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a good idea to open an close the db-file when application become action and when goes to background then close it, always open db and fetch data and close connection. Try to implement the singleton pattern for your database connection class or use sqlite wrapper like FMDB!